# Ubuntu 18.04 Libre Office changing default format settings not possible

Tags: libreoffice, format

In LibreOffice Writer there are pre defined formating defaults for "text" or "Headline 1", "Headline 2" and so on. When changing them, they only stay that way until i quit the programm. After re-opening the programm all modified Formatting schemes a reset to default. i guess i have to run LibreOffice Writer once as root so the changes are permantent? How do I do so? 
Screenshot of Formatting sheme thats keeps resetting to default when closing OfficeWriter:
[image: Screenshot of Formatting sheme thats keeps resetting to default when closing OfficeWriter]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in my Ubuntu 18.04. That is to be saved as [Template](https://easycloudsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215292297-LibreOffice-How-to-Change-Default-Page-Settings).

**To save the Template.**

- Create a document and the content and formatting styles that you want.
- Choose File - Templates - Save As Template.
- In the New Template box, type a name for the new template.
- In the dialog that appears, double-click the "My Templates" folder, and then click Save. You will then be prompted for a name; write it and click OK.

[image: libreoffice]

**To open the template.**

- Choose File - New - Templates.
- Click on Templates.
- Choose your template in My Templates.

**To make it a default Template.**

- Choose File - New - Templates.
- Double-click the "My Templates" folder.
- Click on the template that you created, and click Set as Default.
- Close the dialog.